# ¿Como enviar datos mediante AJAX y JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con dos inputs, uno de tipo text y otro de tipo password. 
 Tengo un boton que envía el formulario, el dicho formulario tiene como destino el archivo "login.php" y mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo enviar los datos mediante AJAX y JQuery para no tener que recargar la pagina, es decir, tengo una sixtaxis basica, me falta saber como llenar dichos campos, a continuación los códigos: 
 Codigo HTML (Formulario):

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
      <label for="inputUser"> Username </label>
      <input type="text" id="inputUser" name ="user">
      <label for="inpuPassword"> Password </label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name ="password">
      <input type="button" id="btnLoginForm" form="loginForm" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Mi estructura basica de AJAX, la idea solo solo saber como llenar esos campos para que envíe los datos.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnLoginForm").click(function(){
        var username = $('#inputUser').val();
        var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
          type:
          url:
          data:
          beforeSend:function(){

          },
          success:function(){

          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Si es posible, quisiera recomendaciones de como recibir los datos en el archivo "login.php" y enviar una respuesta al codigo AJAX para saber si se hizo lo que yo quiero, en este caso una consulta SQL

Comment: Quisiera aclarar que he visto tutoriales pero ninguno me funciona, no se si es porque han salido nuevas versiones o algo por el estilo

Comment: Tienes que enviar un objeto en el parámetro `data`  de la petición, con los datos que quieres, por ejemplo: `var mData= {username: username, password:password}` y en Ajax: `data: mData,` y, para que no se recargue la página, pones `e.preventDefault()` dentro del bloque `$("#btnLoginForm").click(function(){` Los datos del form los puedes obtener también con `serialize()`, es particularmente útil en formularios con muchos campos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviar  un objeto con la data:

```
    $.ajax({
      type:
      url:
      data:
       {usuario:username,password:password},       
      success:function(){

      },
    });
```

Comment: `beforeSend` es una de las configuraciones de Ajax, no es que tenga que ser sustituido por `data` que es otro parámetro.

Comment: si tienes razon yo lo entendi asi: data:beforeSend()